# Radio button for each entry

Tags: html

```html
<table style="margin-top:10px;font-size:18px;">
  <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>CLASS</th>
    <th>ROLL NO.</th>
    <th>ATTENDENCE</th>
  </tr>
  <?php   
               $stream=$_SESSION['stream'];
               $year=$_SESSION['year'];
               $rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE stream='$stream' AND year='$year' ORDER BY roll",$connect);
               while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
               {
          ?>
  <tr>

    <td>
      <?=$row[0]?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?=$row[3]?>
        <?=$row[4]?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?=$row[5]?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="r1" value="p" class="attendence">
      <input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" class="attendence">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <?php
                    }
          ?>

</table>
```

**------------------**
here is the code I am currently working on. I am making online attendance system where I am making the page where teacher will give the attendance to student. I have successfully retrive the name of the student but I am unable to make the radio button for which teacher will give the attendance.. Here 2 radio button appears but among all of these only 1 is working

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is for different students only one radio value is working and applicable to all.

You need an array which specify per row.
so use brackets in name r1[] as i mention.

If not this is the requirement then explain more